# How to find just the direct descendants with HTML::TreeBuilder?

Tags: html, perl, parsing, html-tree

Suppose I've a HTML tree like this:

```
div
`- ul
   `- li          (*)
   `- li          (*)
   `- li          (*)
   `- li          (*)
      `- ul
         `- li
         `- li
         `- li
```

How do I select the `<li>` elements that are marked with `(*)`? They are direct descendants of the first `<ul>` element.

Here is how I find the first `<ul>` element:

```
my $ul = $div->look_down(_tag => 'ul');
```

Now I've the `$ul`, but when I do things like:

```
my @li_elements = $ul->look_down(_tag => 'li');
```

It also finds `<li>` elements that are buried deeper in the HTML tree.

How do I find just the `<li>` elements that are direct descendants of the first `<ul>` element? I've an unknown number of them. (I can't just select first 4 as in example).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get all the children of an [`HTML::Element`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aElement) object using the `content_list` method, so all the child nodes of the first `<ul>` element in the document would be

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file('my.html');

my @items = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'ul')->content_list;
```

But it is far more expressive to use [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath), which lets you find all `<li>` children of `<ul>` children of `<div>` elements anywhere in the document, like this

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file('my.html');

my @items = $tree->findnodes('//div/ul/li')->get_nodelist;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the look_down method you can add an extra criteria to get only the children:

```
my @li_elements = $ul->look_down(_tag => 'li', sub {$_[0]->parent() == $ul});
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this page perfectly complete, I'll add one more option:

```
@li = grep { $_->tag() eq 'li' } $ul->content_list;
```

(Where $ul is your top-level  element)